# Cakephp 3. Image Radio Buttons

Tags: cakephp

Regarding to Cakephp 3 Form Helper,  for Radio Buttons with Images,   i got a question need to ask for help.

From the forumn there's a question, but it was 10 years version earlier, which is not suitable for my codes.

originally the Add.ctp for this item is meant for Type=>Select

```
                  <?php echo $this->Form->control('product_image_id', array('label'  
                     => false, 'div' => false, 
                     'class' => 'form-control', 'type' => 'select', 'empty' => 
                  'Choose Image')); ?>
```

in the Type select, the name of the images only shows out. not the images.

When i want to put the Form Control into the code for the add.ctp

```
              <?php foreach ($product['product_images'] as $productImg) :  ?>
                <div class="container parent">
                   <div class="row">
                  <div class='col text-center'>

                <?php  echo $this->Form->control('product_image_id', ['type' => 
                   'radio', 'escape' => 
                  false, 'class' => 'form-control', 'id' =>$productImg->id, 
                     'name'=>'imgbackground' ]);    ? 
                     > 
                    <label for="<?= $productImg->id ?>">
                    <?php
                   
                    echo $this->Html->image($imgPath, ['width' => '100']);
                    ?>

                     <div class="tick_container">
                        <div class="tick"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></div>
                    </div>
                </label>
               </div>
             </div>
            </div>
           <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Information regarding settings for Form Control for radio buttons is limited....

can anyone help to advise where i went disaligned?

thanks

Comment: So your goal is to put HTML (eg images) in the labels of a list of radio buttons?

Comment: yes,  i would like to achieve something like this link https://codepen.io/munsheerek/pen/QmEWwq

Answer (score 0):

You basically have two options, that is either manipulate the radio options for `FormHelper::control()` to include your custom label contents, or to manually create each label and radio button.

For the former you build an options array that holds nested arrays with `text` and `value` keys, where `text` is the label contents, and `value` the radio button value, eg

```php
[
    ['text' => '<img src="..."> ...', 'value' => '1'],
    ['text' => '<img src="..."> ...', 'value' => '2'],
    // etc ...
]
```

A quick and dirty example could look like this (I'm just guessing here that there's something like a `path` property on your product images, you'll most likely have to adjust this a bit according to your needs to build the proper web path to the image):

```php
echo $this->Form->control('product_image_id', [
    'type' => 'radio',
    'templates' => [
        'radioWrapper' => '{{input}}{{label}}',
        'nestingLabel' => '{{hidden}}<label{{attrs}}>{{text}}</label>',
    ],
    'labelOptions' => [
        'escape' => false,
    ],
    'options' => collection($product['product_images'])
        ->map(function ($productImage) {
            return [
                'text' => 
                    $this->Html->image($productImage->path, ['width' => '100']) .
                    '<div class="tick_container">
                        <div class="tick"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></div>
                    </div>',

                'value' => $productImage->id,
            ];
        }),
]);
```

Note that you need to define custom/modified [**templates**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.10.4/src/View/Helper/FormHelper.php#L101) for the label and the wrapper if you actually need the input to be rendered outside of the label. If you don't actually need it to be rendered that way, then you can drop this example's `templates` option, by default the form helper would render the input inside of the label, eg:

```html
<label><input/>text</label>
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Views > Helper > Form > Creating Radio Buttons](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-radio-buttons)**
- **[Cookbook > Views > Helper > Form > Using Collections to build options](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/views/helpers/form.html#using-collections-to-build-options)**